# INSERT + SELECT FROM + JOIN + ON DUPLICATE KEY MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, insert, on-duplicate-key

For some reason, the combination of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ... CROSS JOIN ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` doesn't seem to work. For instance, I have a table with some numeric information `CREATE TABLE t ( v INT );`, and I would like to copy it into an existing `MEMORY` table `` CREATE TABLE m (id INT DEFAULT 1, v INT, KEY `id` (`id`) ) ENGINE=MEMORY; `` with sequential IDs starting from 1. Instead of deleting everything and re-inserting if the keys exist, I thought I could do the following:

```
INSERT INTO m 
SELECT (@x:=@x+1), v FROM t 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @x:=1) a 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE m.v=t.v;
```

But I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'KEY UPDATE m.v=t.v' at line 1

Yet, the following query runs without error (obviously without the sequential values):

```
INSERT INTO m (v) SELECT v FROM t ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE m.v=t.v;
```

Now, I am aware of `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but I'm asking more generally. I can think of some situations where this query structure would be useful, so what's wrong? I'm running 5.6.20.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46bc68/1) with table structure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is going wrong, but I found a fix:

```
INSERT INTO m 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT (@x:=@x+1) id, v FROM t 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @x:=1) a ) b
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE m.v=b.v;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is addressed in several of the comments on the MySQL documentation for [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Alternatively, if you'd rather keep what you've got instead of overwriting, you can use the following syntax.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO m (v)
SELECT v
FROM t;
```

Comment: Sorry, I read through the comments in the documentation, and couldn't find the comments you are citing. Unless I'm missing a crucial point that is mentioned that implies this not working, nowhere is JOIN behaviour addressed. Could you kindly direct me to the comments you are referring to?

Comment: @concat Ah... I'd missed that the JOIN was what was getting you. I would have to play with the SQL Fiddle to figure it out...